# navigator.getDisplayMedia is not a function in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, get-display-media

I am trying to share user screen and need to use `getDisplayMedia` but getting error during project compile time

> Property 'getDisplayMedia' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Here is the code

```
let stream = await navigator.getDisplayMedia({ video: true })
```

Package versions are as

1. Node v10.14.2
2. NPM v6.5.0
3. @angular/cli v6.1.5

Comment: post your code to understand better

Comment: Ok wait a little please

Comment: The problem is just what the error message says. There is no such property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator

Comment: @WasiF does this error happen in the browser or during compilation? Maybe the method is not available in the browser you are trying. Also, can you try accessing the navigator through the `window` object?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy I have `getDisplayMedia` property on `navigator`.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy getting this error on compile time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Angular 6+`

```
let stream = await navigator.getDisplayMedia({ video: true })
console.log(stream)
```

**Note:** To record the screen in `Angular 6+`, you need to enable `experimental web platform features` in `chrome://flags` until it is launched properly because it is in development and testing mode

see the below image for details:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) you need to use     `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia`

The error you are seeing it because there is no property available with **`navigator`** named **`getDisplayMedia`**

Comment: I think you both are fighting or someone else is doing that ... I am also wonder about that

Comment: I didn't do that, just to clarify :) Have a good day @Sajeetharan

Comment: In which package this `navigator` lie because in my `VS Code` it lies in `navigator.getDisplayMedia`. So what should be update?

Answer (score 3):

If you are in angular you don't getDisplayMedia with navigator or mediaDevices. It shows error on getDisplayMedia. So what you can do to remove the error is.

Declare

`nav: any;`

then where you have to use getDisplayMedia()

`this.nav = navigator;`

`stream = this.nav.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(your content)`

Answer (score 1):

`getDisplayMedia` is no longer available in `navigator`. It was moved to `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia`.

[Source](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-screen-share/pull/86)

Also make sure you have the typing for the [`navigator`](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/phonegap--phonegap/interfaces/navigator.html) installed.

Comment: I have typings for `navigator` but getting red wavy lines under `getDisplayMedia` word

Comment: In which package this navigator lie because in my VS Code it lies in navigator.getDisplayMedia. So what should be update?